# Email from Perl , Cannot locate object method Create

Tags: perl

I am trying to write a script which will send  Gmail from a server using Perl. The code is as shown.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Email::Sender;
use Email::Send::Gmail;
use Email::Simple::Creator;

my $email = Email::Simple->create (
  header => [
    From    => 'xxxx@gmail.com',
    To      => 'yyyyy@gmail.com',
    Subject => 'Oh no! The bathwater is overflowing!',
  ],
  body => 'The bath water is overflowing.',
);
my $sender = Email::Send->new ({
    mailer      => 'Gmail',
    mailer_args => [
        username => 'xxxxx',
        password => 'yyyyy',
    ]
});

$sender->send ($email);
For which I get the error  `Can't locate object method "create" via package "Email::Simple" at file.pl line 9.`
```

What is causing this error as I have installed Email::Simple Module and Gmail Modules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing `use Email::Simple;` as [`perldoc suggests`](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/RJBS/Email-Simple-Creator-1.424/lib/Email/Simple/Creator.pm#SYNOPSIS).